# Navigator of and Navigator pop differences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Can anyone tell me if there is a difference between using `Navigator.of(context).pop()` vs `Navigator.pop(context)` when closing a modal (using showDialog or Alert from rflutter_alert) as both close the modal?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Source code 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2a8e7b7bf162e672141a73180214a9eb9033251d/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L1487

```
@optionalTypeArgs
  static void pop<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, [ T result ]) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop<T>(result);
  }
```

`Navigator.pop(context)` call `Navigator.of(context).pop()`